# Volume inside region delimited by surfaces $z=5-x^2$, $z=y$ and $y=1$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to find the volume inside the region $E$ delimited by surfaces $z=5-x^2$, $z=y$ and $y=1$.

I've spent few hours on this and would really need a hint from a charitable soul. I see that the parabolic cylinder $z=5-x^2$ is intersected by the planes $z=y$ and $y=1$.

Projected to the $xy$ plane, I think the region is delimited by $y=5-x^2$ and $y=1$, since $z=y=5-x^2$. Thus, I assume the integral would be :

$\int_{-2}^2(\int_1^{5-x^2}5-x^2dy)dx$

However, I'm sure this is not correct... Isn't it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's right. One side of the region is $z=y$, and another side is $z = 5-x^2$, so you don't want to assume both conditions are holding at once.

I drew the region, and it seems they're looking for $1 \leq y \leq z \leq 5-x^2$. I think the projection onto the $xy$ plane is not the easiest. If we instead project onto the $xz$ plane, we integrate over $-2 \leq x \leq 2,\,\,\,$ $1 \leq z \leq 5-x^2$. Then in the $y$ direction we need only integrate $1 \leq y \leq z$, so we get $$\int_{-2}^2 \int_{1}^{5-x^2} \int_{1}^z \,dy\,dz\,dx. $$

It's hard to demonstrate without drawing a picture, but I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Eric. I understand what you mean, but can't manage to express the integral in this case. You would want to integrate over x and z with the bounds you mentionned? Then what would be the integrand? Thank you.

Comment: And don't we have to integrate z over sqrt(5) <= z <= 5 - x^2, instead?

Comment: The integrand is always one when you're finding volume. I don't see why you'd integrate $\sqrt{5} \leq z $...can you explain your thinking?

Comment: I'm not very skilled at calculus and had just figured out a minute before your post that this really can't be done with a double integral. I think I now understand, your answer makes sense to me now. Thank you very much !

Comment: You're welcome. You *could* do it with a double integral...just integrate $z-1$ with the bounds like the outer two integrals.